# AndroidX native camera

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, photo

I'm an android developer beginner and i try to use CameraX.
Is it possible to open the native camera and take a picture instead of build a page with preview and custom button to take a photo ?
I've read multiple article / tutorial but cannot find the solution.
Thanks for helping me

Comment: Did you check: https://github.com/android/camera-samples ?

Comment: @gioravered yep ! but the problem is i have to build a specific layout for the camera

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Tanoukis Please check the answer below and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0), with a few tweaks - I was able to take a photo without any preview.

First we start the camera using ImageCapture use case:

```
private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .build()
        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
        try {
            // Unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            // Bind use cases to camera
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, imageCapture)
        } catch(exc: Exception) {
            Log.e("Error", "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}
```

Then we can take a photo by calling takePhoto method:

```kotlin
private fun takePhoto() {
    // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
    val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

    // Create time stamped name and MediaStore entry.
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "sample_image")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/CameraX-Image")
        }
    }

    // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
    val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
        .Builder(contentResolver,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            contentValues)
        .build()

    // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
    // been taken
    imageCapture.takePicture(
        outputOptions,
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e("Error", "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun
                    onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults){
                val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${output.savedUri}"
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d("Success", msg)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I've uploaded a working project to [Github](https://github.com/gioravered/camera-x-no-preview)

Comment: I've try to implement but the camera never open, i have the same issue with your project. I've try to gitclone and launch but the camera never launch

Comment: Is it a real device or an Emulator? Are you approving the permission request that is prompted? How do you know the camera doesn't launch?